# How can I echo the key name itself in PHP

Tags: php, function, class

```
<form name="contact" method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="first_name">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I would like to echo `first_name` string. Even when the value for `name="first_name"` is not set.

What exactly I'm trying to achieve?
See the variable $name, I'd like it to echo `first_name`.
So, lets say I add another input to my form,

```
<input type="text" name="surname">
```

I would like my function `check_empty` to say : **"Please don't leave the surname field empty."** As well as: "Please don't leave the name field empty."

```
    class validator{        
    function check_empty($first_name){
        if(empty($first_name)){
            echo "Please don't leave the $first_name field empty.";
        }
    }   
}
```

**Edit.**
basicaly what im trying to do is use one function only to validate all the empty fields. and show them relevant message so if firstname field is empty, tell them its empty. if surname is empty, tell them it's empty. I do not want to use more than one functions to validate different empty fields.

Comment: How do you call `check_empty`?

Comment: @hd  
http://pastebin.com/gCkgudVQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're looping through `$_POST` and calling `check_empty`. In that case, do the following

```
$objValidator = new validator();
$arrErrors = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $arrErrors[] = $objValidator->check_empty($key, $value);
}
array_filter($arrErrors); //Remove FALSE values, so only actual errors are stored

if( count($arrErrors) ) { 
   echo implode("<br />", $arrErrors);
   //Show form?
} else {
   //Everything is filled in
}
```

Then, just modify your method;

```
function check_empty($key, $value){
    if(empty($value)){
        return "Please don't leave the ". $key ." field empty.";
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: @HD basicaly what im trying to do is use one function only to validate all the empty fields. and show them relevant message so if firstname field is empty, tell them its empty. if surname is empty, tell them it's empty. I do not want to use more than one functions to validate different empty fields.

Comment: This is using one method. We are looping through your `_POST`'d data, and checking each one with your one `check_empty` method. Each field goes through your one method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate this before the user submites the value, you have to do this with JS

If you want to validate with PHP, you have to check if submit is pressed and check first name value:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //check first name value
    if(isset($_POST['first_name']) && $_POST['first_name'] != '') {
       //enter code here
    } else {
       echo "Please don't leave the $_POST['first_name'] field empty.";
    }
}
```

alternatively, to use your function:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    check_empty($_POST['first_name']);
    //do whatever
}
```

with class:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $validation = new validator();
    $validation->check_empty($_POST['first_name']);
}
```

**L.E:** I will use the latter example that I provided. SO:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $validation = new validator();

    //you do this for every `_POST` you have
    $values = array();
    $values['label'] = 'First Name'; 
    $values['value'] = $_POST['first_name'];

    $validation->check_empty($values); 
}

//check_empty needs a small adjustment now:
function check_empty($value){
    if(empty($value['value'])){
        echo "Please don't leave the " . $value['label'] . " field empty.";
    }
}
```

Hope it helps! 
Keep on coding! 
Ares.

Comment: In your examples that use the method `check_empty`, it doesn't give OPs desired result.

Comment: ok, I will modify my answer in a moment. Tx for pointing that out for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can get names of empty fields in one line:

```
$empty_fields = array_keys(array_diff_key($_POST, array_filter($_POST)));
```

Remember about KISS - keep it simple, stupid.

Answer (score 0):

alright with you guys' help this is what i did. it pretty much gives me the desired result.

```
    class validator{        
    function check_empty($post_array){
        foreach($post_array as $key=>$value){
            if(empty($value)){
                echo $key . " field cannot be left empty" . "</br>";
            }
        }
    }
}

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $Validator = new validator();
    $Validator->check_empty($_POST);
}
```

Thanks one again : )